# ¿Es posible terminar la instalacion de Encore sin tener Yarn o Node instalados?

Tags: php, nodejs, symfony, yarn

He creado una aplicación de prueba basada en Symfony en un hosting compartido. Una de las limitaciones es que, al ser hosting compartido no tengo permisos root.

La instalación de Symfony se hizo sin aparente problema, y creé el proyecto Demo de Symfony en una carpeta del hosting. La App se creó y puedo navegar en ella, pero los archivos `.js` y `.css` no se están cargando. Explorando la consola veo que no los encuentra, porque los está buscando en una carpeta `build` que no existe (actualmente los archivos `.js`  y `.css` están en la carpeta `assets`).

Leyendo [la documetación de Symfony](https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/installation.html) dice que esto se puede resolver con la ayuda de `Encore`.

Bien, he instalado `Encore` sin problema mediante composer:

```
composer require symfony/webpack-encore-bundle
```

La instalación se hace bien, ningún error, pero me dice esto al final:

> Don't forget to run `npm install --force` or `yarn install --force` to
> refresh your Javascript dependencies! Run composer recipes at any time
> to see the status of your Symfony recipes.

Aquí es donde viene el problema, porque no tengo ni `yarn` ni `npm` en mi hosting.

Intento instalar `yarn` y lo consigo vía `curl`  con este comando que sugieren en [este sitio](https://www.a2hosting.es/kb/installable-applications/manual-installations/installing-and-configuring-yarn-on-managed-hosting-accounts):

```
curl -o- -L https://yarnpkg.com/install.sh | bash
```

La instalación ocurre sin error, pero al final me dice esto:

> Yarn requires Node.js 4.0 or higher to be installed.
>
> > Yarn was installed, but doesn't seem to be working :(.

Pues reviso las formas de instalar Node y niguna me funciona. Y por otro lado me parece demasiado tener que instalar Node para esto, no voy a usar Node, simplemente quiero implementar las prácticas recomendadas en mi proyecto Symfony.

Por eso mi pregunta: ¿hay algún modo de instalar/usar Encore sin tener que instalar Node?

Comment: `Webpack Encore` es solo para desarrollo, en producción no lo vas usar. Un dato vital es que [`Webpack Encore`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend.html#webpack-encore) requiere [`webpack`](https://webpack.js.org/guides/getting-started/) el cual requiere `nodejs`... es una cadena de dependencias...

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario, @Marcos. Dado que estoy empezando con Symfony, al crear un proyecto de prueba directamente en una carpeta de mi hosting los archivos `.js` y `.css` no se cargan, porque los está buscando en la carpeta `build`, pero dichos archivos están en `assets`, vi en la doc que la mejor manera de resolver esto era con `Encore`. ¿Sabes si hay alguna otra forma? Yo creé un proyecto de prueba en local y funcionó perfecto, pero en el hosting tengo este problema.